# Pass separate value into template function

Tags: go

I am trying to find a way to pass value into go template function.
What i mean. I have template functions list defined in struct method:

```
func (o *MyObj) run() error{
  funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "func1": func1,
    "func2": func2,
    }
}
```

Function1 signature is `func func1(myval string) string{...}`, but for Function2 id need to have access to one of MyObj struct field. 
Mean:

```
func func2(myval string) string{
//MyObj.field would need to be used here.. How can i do it?
}
```

Comment: `func (this *MyObj)func2(myval string) string{}` and in the map `"func2":myobj.func2`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JiangYD!

Comment: also :`template.FuncMap{ "func2" : func(myval string) string { return origFunc(myval, othervar, anotherVar) } }`  the othevar and anothervar are available in this context (a global var, a local var in this scope or ...)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @JiangYD

```
func (o *MyObj)func2(myval string) string{}`

func (o *MyObj) run() error{
  funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "func1": func1,
    "func2": o.func2,
    }
}
```